# Homebrew started blowing up, no idea why

Tags: homebrew

I probably did some unwise things. After a `brew update` and a `brew doctor` kept throwing the same error, I tried to uninstall and reinstall it with the shell scripts for those. They mostly worked but upon reinstall, I got the same error bookended by the normal homebrew install output. So now in addition to losing homebrew itself, I've lost all the brew-installed tools. It's unclear what I've screwed up to cause this. Error output below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    15: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:23:in `<main>'
    14: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:23:in `require_relative'
    13: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    12: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n/backend/simple.rb:50:in `available_locales'
    11: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n/backend/simple.rb:80:in `init_translations'
    10: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:18:in `load_translations'
     9: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:18:in `each'
     8: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:18:in `block in load_translations'
     7: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:226:in `load_file'
     6: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:243:in `load_yml'
     5: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.3_1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/psych.rb:577:in `load_file'
     4: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.3_1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/psych.rb:577:in `open'
     3: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.3_1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/psych.rb:578:in `block in load_file'
     2: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.3_1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/psych.rb:277:in `load'
     1: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.3_1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/psych.rb:390:in `parse'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.3_1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/psych.rb:455:in `parse_stream': uninitialized constant Psych::Handlers (NameError)
    10: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:23:in `<main>'
     9: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:23:in `require_relative'
     8: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
     7: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n/backend/simple.rb:50:in `available_locales'
     6: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n/backend/simple.rb:80:in `init_translations'
     5: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:18:in `load_translations'
     4: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:18:in `each'
     3: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:18:in `block in load_translations'
     2: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:226:in `load_file'
     1: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:241:in `load_yml'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:245:in `rescue in load_yml': can not load translations from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/locale/en.yml: #<NameError: uninitialized constant Psych::Handlers> (I18n::InvalidLocaleData)
```

Comment: As this is only a comment, and not an answer.... I'd be very inclined to make a backup and then `rm -rf /usr/local/{Cellar,Homebrew}` and start again.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Those directories were nuked with the uninstall. Reinstall didn't fix it, continue to get the same stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

Hope I am not too late for this thread, I have definitely seen this issue before.

Can you try the following two lines to see if it helps?

```
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.3_1/bin/gem update --system
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.3_1/bin/gem pristine --all
```

Worst case is you just need to remove `~/.gems`, and brew would re-download the gem dependencies.

If would be great that you can attach your MacOS information.

Comment: I have since fixed my installation. Required a few rm -rf commands, the details were on the homebrew forums. Keeping this post handy though if it ever happens again.

Comment: Yeah, homebrew forum is a good place that we keep monitoring, and hope you never run into this issue again.